# Alt+F2 (Run Application) doesn't work for custom commands

Tags: paths

In order to speed up Android development, I've edited my `~/.bashrc` to add some paths to `PATH`:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools
```

This works just fine from the command line (I can just type `android` and, no matter where I am, the Android SDK and AVD Manager will start up just fine.

However, if I try to type `android` in the <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> dialog (Run Application), it gives the following error:

> **Could not open location 'file:///home/felix/android'**
>
> Error stating file '/home/felix/android': No such file or directory

Why is that? What `PATH` does the Run Application dialog use?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume the `bashrc` is not read by Gnome, and why should it, since it is a config file for `bash`.

I define my path in `~/.profile`. This file is definitely read by the Gnome and XFCE environments and should by others as well. (But it is read only on login, so you have to log out and back in any the changes to take effect!)

Comment: I moved the `PATH=` statement to `~/.profile` and it works both in Alt+F2 and a terminal. Thanks.

Comment: In my case, I couldn't figure out how to make the X session to start with a login shell so it would read the `~/.profile`, so I had to change /bin/sh to point to /bin/dash

Comment: Hey, this is Gnome 3.30.1 speaking, and setting the PATH in `~/.profile` does not work anymore. Is there any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

`~/.bashrc` is included by `~/.profile` by default. The `~/bin` directory is added to `PATH` by default too. Create the `~/bin` directory and add sym-links (`ln -s`) to applications you intent to use, or modify your `~/.bashrc`.

The default content of the mentioned files can be found in `/etc/skel` -- used while creating new account and their home directories.

Comment: Yes, if `.profile` is being executed by a `bash`! The conditional checks for the `$BASH_VERSION` being defined, which Gnome won't do. And by the way, removing the condition will result in problems with some desktop environments, such as LXDE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Linux Mint (Cinnamon 2.8.8), and there was no way I could get it working with the usual fixes (using a `.profile`, changing `Xsession` shebang to `/bin/sh -l`).

The issue is that `/bin/sh`, which is usually a symlink to `/bin/dash` reads `~/.profile` if it's a login shell (i.e., given the `-l` option).

You can check that with strace:

```
$ strace -e open dash
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)                = 3
$ ^D
+++ exited with 0 +++
$ strace -e open dash -l
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)                = 3
open("/etc/profile", O_RDONLY)          = 3
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=12260, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
open("/etc/profile.d/Z97-byobu.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/etc/profile.d/vte.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/home/elias/.profile", O_RDONLY)  = 3
$ ^D
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

I couldn't figure out which script to change (tried a bunch of them under /etc/X11 and /etc/mdm), but no luck.

So I threw the towel and changed `/bin/sh` to point to `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/dash` and it's working now. :)