# Trouble starting MATLAB via Alt+F2

Tags: command-line, matlab, paths

I've recently installed MATLAB to `/opt/matlab/R2016a` and I've managed to give myself the privilidges to run it. Next I wanted to be able to run it from a terminal and or the <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> "quick command line" so I added `export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/matlab/R2016a/bin` (where the executeable `matlab` is located) to `~/.profile` as was suggested in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19970/altf2-run-application-doesnt-work-for-custom-commands) thread.

Thanks to this I was able to run MATLAB from a terminal by simply typing `matlab` and the program would start normally as you'd expect. But when I tried to run it using <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> and typing `matlab` the splash screen did appear, but the program didn't launch.

I was under the impression that <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> just opened a "one line terminal" to quickly execute something, but it doesn't seem to work from there.

Shouldn't I be able to run it like this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `~/.profile` is read (and thus the `PATH` is set) only once during the start-up of your environment (I assume you're using Gnome here?). So your edit will be in effect when you open a terminal (because it starts a new shell instance, which reads in your `~/.profile`), but for the <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> to work, your Gnome shell would need to restart. The easiest way to achieve this is to log out and then log in again.

Comment: I was aware of this due to the mentioned thread and I not only logged in and out, but rebooted the whole system between changes and it still doesn't work.
And like I say, the splash screen appears and the process is active for a few seconds (when using <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> ), which I was able to confirm using ```top```, but the program seems to shut itself down, before it can fully open.
And like I say the program runs without problem when run from a terminal.